# How to populate checkboxlist and set checkboxlist item selected as per IsActive field..?

Tags: sql, asp.net

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chboxlistskill" Font-Bold="true" ToolTip="Skill" 
CssClass="chboxlistskill" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="3"> 

<%--AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="chboxlistskill_SelectedIndexChanged">--%>
</asp:CheckBoxList>

IsActive SkillID    SkillType
    1       1       C
    1       2       C++
    0       3       SQL
    1       4       Oracle
    0       5       ASP.NET
    0       6       Javascript
    0       7       JQuery
    0       8       Linux
```

How to load above table list into checkboxlist and display all list but keep selected only items that are set to 1 in IsActive field...?

Comment: You need to add `ListItem` objects either decoratively or programtically, check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Here is your answer http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-CheckBoxList-from-Database-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Thnx Sachin.....! :-)